# Tensorflow SSD300 for Android

Tags: android, tensorflow

I'm a college student who studies machine leraning in Japan.
I'm not good at using English, but I will make efforts to convey my situation in English.

I'm now trying to use the object detection model for android.
I used SSD300_mobile_net for training and then I got .hdf5 file which has model's weights.

Next, I convert this .hdf5file into .pb file which is fit for tensorflow.
At last, I want to use this .pb file for tensorflow android .(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android)

But I got an error on Android Studio as below while debugging the application by using my device

[This is the error capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB6Eo.png)
I want to know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I sense that it's an issue with your hardware. Generally the hdf5 files are very big and even bigger is the computation that is being done on it. Since your system is giving OOM exception, I believe you are getting this error while loading weights into the model.